# Save received JSON information into database

Tags: php, json, yii2

I have a client in angular that sends to my server side in YII2 a JSON with all information about a quote.
This is the JSON received in the server side.

```
{  
   "client1":{  
      "id":"1",
      "selectedItem":{  
         "id":2,
         "software":"TV",
         "price":14850,
         "configuration":1,
         "workflow":1.5
      },
      "quantity":1,
      "locations":22,
      "notes":"hello",
      "cost":13500,
      "labor":"1.63",
      "workflow":1.5,
      "custom":0,
      "learning":35,
      "price":13500,
      "configuration":1
   },
   "client2":{  
      "id":"2",
      "selectedItem":{  
         "id":5,
         "software":"DVD",
         "price":2500,
         "configuration":0.5,
         "workflow":1.5
      },
      "quantity":2,
      "locations":136,
      "notes":"its me",
      "cost":5000,
      "labor":0,
      "workflow":1.5,
      "custom":0,
      "$$hashKey":"object:5",
      "price":2500,
      "configuration":0.5
   },
   "live":"11",
   "training":"1",
   "staffTraining":"4"
}
```

Its needed to create a record in the database but don't know how to access the products information can only access to `live`, `training` and `staffTraining` keys.

This is the tables I want to insert the record

[image: Database Diagram]

Server code to add quote

```
public function actionCreate() {
    $model = new Quote();
    Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;

    if ($data=Yii::$app->request->post() ) {
        $model->attributes = $data;
        if($model->save()) {
            echo(json_encode("success"));
        } else {
            echo json_encode($model->errors);
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Your JSON is malformed.

Comment: @AlessioCantarella JSON is fixed

Answer (score 0):

YOu can try this,

```
 public function actionCreate(){
    Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    if ($data=Yii::$app->request->post()){
        $responseArray=json_decode($data,true);
        foreach ( $responseArray as  $response) {
            $model = new Quote();
            $model->attributes=$response;
            $model->save();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your json format is not correct. you can check in https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: You could probably try to have the person sending you the JSON data with a sub key for product info in a format that can be easily loaded into your model.